# PostgreSQL - Unir tablas en base a la cantidad de columnas

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables

Estoy trabajando en PostgreSQL, y lo que quiero obtener es todas la UNION de todas las tablas que tienen 11 columnas en una base que se llama "postgres".

La lista de dichas tablas que quiero unir la obtuve de la siguiente manera:

```
with  
completo_tablas as (
select column_name, table_name from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='public'
)
--,tablas as (
select table_name--, count(column_name)
from completo_tablas
group by table_name
having count(column_name)=11
--)
```

Obteniendo algo asi como:

```
Table_name
--------------  
table1  
table2  
.  
.  
.
```

La *dificultad* que no logro superar, no es unir las tablas resultantes para  un día en particular; dado que copiando los nombres de las tablas a mano puedo hacer el

```
Select * from tabla1 UNION select * from tabla2 UNION Sel....
```

Sino que , dado la naturaleza de nuestro negocio, se pueden ir agregando tablas. Entonces no quiero una query *estática*, donde tenga los nombres de las tablas a unir "escritos a mano"; sino algo que se pueda ejecutar siempre con ese objetivo: unir todas las tablas de esa base que tengan 11 columnas.

(vale aclarar, que tampoco queremos ir agregando los nombres de las nuevas tablas a mano).

Escucho sus sugerencias, y agradezco su tiempo.

Saludos

Comment: Estás muy mal, eso no es un buen diseño. En todo caso necesitas una sola tabla con 12 columnas en la que tengas las 11 columnas de tus tablas y una que sea el identificador entre cada conjunto de datos.

Comment: Luis. La verdad que no entendi nada de lo que sugerís. Quedo atento a tus comentarios